# Can I keep my local account user name for the user login list when I add sign in with Microsoft Account?

Tags: windows, windows-10, user-accounts, login, username

**Background**

I have separate local Windows accounts for work, home, my own projects and my involvment in software communities.

I created a 'Rob Davis (Work)' local windows account (administrator level).  This created a folder in C:Users by the same name.  I then set this account to use login with Microsoft account.

I noticed that when logging in, the account is shown as just "Rob Davis", without the "(Work)". So presumably, the user name displayed is being taken from my Microsoft login rather than my local Windows user account name.  This is unhelpful, because I now cannot see if this account I am selecting is "Rob Davis (Work)".

Any way to retain the user name from the local Windows account for the list of accounts to choose to login from?

Comment: What other account with the same name do you have on the computer? Or do you have two Microsoft accounts with the same name?

Comment: If you use use different names for local and Microsoft Account, they will both show up on Log in. I have that running here on Windows 10.

Comment: If you don't mind having (Work) in the title everywhere, you can also login to your profile on the microsoft site and change it there. Might need a reboot after sync to show it locally though...

Comment: @therobyouknow - [Here](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-change-account-name-windows-10-sign-screen) is how you do what LPChip is talking about.